# DefaultTrackSelector in ExoPlayer not working ! (other way?)

Tags: java, android, http-live-streaming, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am developing a live stream and movie player application. I chose ExoPlayer 2. The movie has two different tracks include (English and Persian). In others i found these solutiones but not working for me. I want sth like a button in playing movie that when i click, it switches between tracks. can you help me?

```
trackSelector.setParameters(
trackSelector
    .buildUponParameters()
    .setMaxVideoSizeSd()
    .setPreferredAudioLanguage("fa"));
```

and also

```
trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector();
trackSelector.setParameters(
        trackSelector.getParameters().buildUpon().setMaxVideoSizeSd()
        .setPreferredTextLanguage("fa")
        .setPreferredAudioLanguage("fa").build());
```